# CSS issue with an image

Tags: html, css

How to make.

```css
.l {
  float: left
}
.abs {
  position: absolute
}
.rl {
  position: relative
}
.r {
  float: right
}
.f {
  clear: both
}
.menuItem {
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid
}
.menuItem .p {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px
}
.menuItem .active {
  color: #333;
  cursor: default
}
.menuItem a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer
}
.menuItem .p:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f6;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div class='menuItem'>
  <div class='l' style='margin-left:120px'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class='l p active'>Info
    <a href="<% $URL %><% $_GET[0] %>" class="active b"></a>
  </div>
  <a href="<% $URL %><% $_GET[0] %>/forums">
    <div class='l p'>Forums (105)</div>
  </a>
  <div class='f'></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyPSV/6gh2dfm4/1/

Image under (center position) `.active` as such:

(white background, consistent with the border_bottom)

[image]

and background: `#fff` when you hover on ALL active?

Comment: I think you have to explain a bit more detailed.

Comment: Can you show some code where you actually used your image?

Comment: I want to place image under the `<div class='l p active'>Info<a href="<% $URL %><% $_GET[0] %>" class="active b"></a></div>` + when you hover on it, I want background:#fff (on all button)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyPSV/6gh2dfm4/1/

Comment: I cannot see any image being used in that demo... :| Also in the image you're showing us there's some gray underneath it... what about it? I cannot see it fit in your demo

Comment: I think the problem is with your ASP. If you output the values of `<% URL %><% $_GET[0] %>` That should help, too.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to create a small image of a triangle and to use the `background` css property on the class `.active` to position that image in the middle of the bottom. When hovering over the `.active` you can set the background to none. For example:

```
.active {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/9x9') center bottom no-repeat;
}
.active:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

Another option might be not to use an image at all and to use create a triangle in a `:after` selector using css.

```css
.l {
  float: left
}
.abs {
  position: absolute
}
.rl {
  position: relative
}
.r {
  float: right
}
.f {
  clear: both
}
.menuItem {
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid
}
.menuItem .p {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px
}
.menuItem .active {
  color: #333;
  cursor: default
}
.menuItem a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer
}
.menuItem .p:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f6;
  text-decoration: none
}

.active {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/9x9') center bottom no-repeat;
}
.active:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='menuItem'>
  <div class='l' style='margin-left:120px'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class='l p active'>Info
    <a href="<% $URL %><% $_GET[0] %>" class="active b"></a>
  </div>
  <a href="<% $URL %><% $_GET[0] %>/forums">
    <div class='l p'>Forums (105)</div>
  </a>
  <div class='f'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image works ideally, but it hides when I hover on it and it should be placed 1px below the actual position. I seek exactly for http://s17.postimg.org/c7paspcij/fb_timeline.gif?noCache=1418555362 but with the white background like on the example (white background doesn't works on your example).

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a `border-bottom` and an `background-image` as the border will be on top of the background image. One solution could be to make a really wide image, but I would suggest you to go for a solution with a pseudo selector.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:pseudo` element for adding triangle at the bottom

```css
.l {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.abs {
  position: absolute
}
.rl {
  position: relative
}
.r {
  float: right
}
.f {
  clear: both
}
.menuItem {
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid
}
.menuItem .p {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px
}
.menuItem .active {
  color: #333;
  cursor: default
}
.menuItem a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer
}
.menuItem .p:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f6;
  text-decoration: none
}
.l.active:after {
  content: '';
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 9px 10px 9px;
  border-color: rgb(233, 234, 237) transparent;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -11px;
}
.l.active:before {
  content: '';
  bottom: -1px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 10px 11px 10px;
  border-color: #ccc transparent;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class='menuItem'>
  <div class='l' style='margin-left:120px'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class='l p active'>Info
    <a href="<% $URL %><% $_GET[0] %>" class="active b"></a>

  </div>
  <a href="<% $URL %><% $_GET[0] %>/forums">
    <div class='l p'>Forums (105)</div>
  </a>

  <div class='f'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've copied & paste code from the example above, but it doesn't want to work. I seek exactly for http://s17.postimg.org/c7paspcij/fb_timeline.gif?noCache=1418555362 but with the white background like on the example (+ no background when hover on .active).

Comment: It shows, but on the bottom of page. How to position in absolute 'divs' is an issue.